# Модификаторы доступа без наследования в С++

Tags: c++

Всем привет!
Есть такой вопрос.
Какую роль играют модификаторы доступа в С++ перед определением класса.
Допустим, у нас есть класс

```
private class Location {
public:     
    int X; int Y;   
public:            
    Location();
        Location (int InitX, int InitY); 
    ~Location();
 };
```

нет наследования, к примеру
Вопрос в том, что изменится, если менять модификатор здесь `private[ protected, public] class Location`. 
Как я не менял, ничего не изменилось, если менять модификаторы у полей, то  да, там разница ощутима. А в С++, не как в Java и C#, не понятно что я этими модификаторами перед определением класса.
Всем спасибо за внимание. Буду признателен, если кто-то сможет помочь в решении данной проблемы.

Comment: @Илья Ольчиков, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А какой у Вас компилятор?

Comment: visual studio, там компилится все.

Answer (score 1):

Они не играют никакой роли. То есть, их там вовсе нет, в отличие, скажем, от Java или C#, где модификаторы доступа могут применяться к классам, указывая на их видимость относительно пространства имен. В С++ модификаторы доступа к классам не применяются, а потому подобный код приведет к ошибке компиляции

Comment: он компилируется в студии и никаких ошибок не выдает.
Вы уверены, что разницы абсолютно никакой нет для С++?

Comment: @Илья Ольчиков эммм..в какой студии?

Comment: visual studio 2012 express

Comment: @DreamChild, вы уверены, что модификаторы перед классом в С++ не играют никакой роли?

Comment: @Илья Ольчиков  вы уверены, что у вас это компилируется? 

В VS12 это не работает. Вот пример

[alt text][1]


А [вот еще пример][2], уже с другим компилятором

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/5Sw4gWG.png

[2]:http://ideone.com/KfDRg5

Comment: ээээм...видимо, дело в том, есть ли наследник у класса
http://imgur.com/LaX88FO
в этом случае код компилируется, но влияния модификаторов я все равно не наблюдаю.

Comment: @Илья Ольчиков покажите весь код проекта. И class.h и class.cpp и main.cpp

Comment: @DreamChild, вот, в суть программы, думаю, вникать не стоит, это всего лишь лаба по ООП)
https://yadi.sk/d/azjHK5baeyteV

Comment: @DreamChild, думаю, дальнейшее обсуждение не нужно. Разобрался. Такой код действительно не должен компилироваться.
Видимо, это был какой-то баг в VS

Comment: @DreamChild: Могу поспорить, у ТС проект под C++/CLI.

Comment: @VladD, там же `ref class` вместо `class` надо, так что вряд ли.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, может, что-то ещё более древнее? Managed C++ там. (И я не помню, что C++/CLI разрешает для нативных классов.)